# BasicFileAttributes vs BasicFileAttributeView in Java

Tags: java, attributes, metadata

What is the difference between these two interfaces? [BasicFileAttributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) vs [BasicFileAttributeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributeView.html)

I understand that they serve to retrieve basic metadata from a file, but what actually differs from each other?

**EDIT:** I previously meant that in the following example the 2 interfaces are used interchangeably. Is there any difference at all? besides the fact that in order to access the attributes with the view first you have to call the `.readAttributes()` method?

```
BasicFileAttributeView bs = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, BasicFileAttributeView.class);
        BasicFileAttributes bfa = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are nothing but the signatures they describe. So the difference between these two interfaces are, that they demand methods of other signatures implemented.

If you have a BasicFileAttributeView instance, you can get a BasicFileAttributes using `readAttributes()`. If you don't have a BasicFileAttributeView (BFAV) instance, you can get it using [Files.getFileAttributeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getFileAttributeView%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29). It is guaranteed that you can pass BFAV, even if it may not work with every subclass of FileAttributeView.

Example:

```
BasicFileAttributeView  bfav    = Files.getFileAttributeView(
                                   FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/dev/null"),
                                   BasicFileAttributeView.class
                                  );
BasicFileAttributes     bfa     = bfav.readAttributes();
System.out.println(bfa.lastAccessTime());
```

1. We get the default FileSystem, so that we can use it in the next step.
2. We get a Path using the FileSystem, so that we can use it in the next step
3. We get the **BasicFileAttributeView** (which **represents the ability to read a BasicFileAttribute**) using the Path, so that ...
4. We get the BasicFileAttribute using the BasicFileAttributeView, so that ...
5. We get the lastAccessTime (a FileTime), ...
6. We print it using [FileTime::toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#toString--)

Comment: Ok I edited my question with more info. Thanks a lot for the answer as of now.

Comment: So basically are they interchangeable as I added in my latest edit

Comment: @Rollerball: "interchangeable" means you can always swap one for the other. That is not the case. In terms of set theory, they are not even  bijective, since you can't get a fully working BasicFileAttributeView form a BasicFileAttributes. But you have probably will **never have a reason to use BFAView unless you want to set the creation time or the access time**, because, as you mentioned in your question, you can get the BFA easily by using that other helper method.

Comment: So basically the view gives only some extra methods that might be useful to the programmer and they are not comprised in the BFA method as it would go against the cohesion of the program design, isn'it?

Comment: @Rollerball: You need the view to modify the data in the BFA. Dividing it like this could make it easy to see where you are modifying attributes. The reason that you can get the BFA from it's view is probably that you can read the attributes if you can write them. You could say that this division constitutes a cohesion of readable and writable objects (relating to the same data). A term like "against the cohesion of the program design" is too vague for me :)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen can you tell where BFAView should be used and where BFA should be used. I mean what are the situations where one of them should be used.

Comment: Just use BFA until you find out you may need the BFAView, which probably won't happen.

Comment: Which implementation is typically better performing? I read in a test prep guide that FileAttributeView has fewer round trips and is therefore more performant.  But, that doesn't make sense to me, because View offers dynamic access, which would mean no caching and more round trips.  Seems like if I want to hit the object a lot, say in a file system scan stream op, it would make sense to use the Attributes instance.